# count year from date column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to see count of years from date column in a dataframe.

I have a df column like this

```
df =       Date
      2014-03-18 00:00:00
      2014-04-23 12:00:00
      2015-01-12 01:00:00
      2016-05-24 00:00:00
      2017-11-12 00:00:00
      2017-08-18 00:00:00
```

I would like to see output like below:

```
Date
2014-2
2015-1
2016-1
2017-2
```

Comment: typo? `2107, 2104`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Date'].dt.year.value_counts().sort_index()
```

Output

```
2014    2
2015    1
2016    1
2017    2
```